# Is the exponencial of an operator a definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, operator-theory

I am a physics undergraduate and me and my colleagues were discussing if the exponential of an operator is just a definition or it comes up from more fundamental concepts. I would like an explanation from where it was first used or most common area of use in mathematics and the validity of this operation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about the matrix exponential?

Comment: Yes, because linear operators can be represented by a matrix. Does this relation is valid for non linear operators?

Comment: Yes, $$e^A:= I+A+\frac1{2!} A^2+\cdots$$ is the definition of the matrix exponential. I don't know if this is just for it to be analogous the exponential of scalars, or if there is a more fundamental reason

Comment: Well, the exponential of an operator is used widely in physics because it connects the Lie algebra (infinitesimal generators of a symmetry transformation, as physicists call it) of a Lie group to the group itself, where elements of the group are global transformations of the system. This is often seen in quantum mechanics. I have never seen an exponential be defined for nonlinear operators. In physics, almost all Lie groups you encounter are matrix Lie groups , so that you only need to learn the 'matrix definition' of the exponential map. But it mathematical terms, it is vastly more general.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you solve an $n$ dimensional (usually $n=2$) system of ODE's with constant coefficients (see harmonic oscillator), the matrix exponential comes up in solving ODE's of the form
$$
\vec{x}'(t)=A\vec{x(t)}\implies \vec{x}(t)=\exp(At)\vec{x_0}
$$
Where it is safe to define $\exp(At)$ by it's series expansion.

A less tame place: the time evolution equation for a particle governed by Schroëdinger's equation is given by an operator exponential. Namely, if 
$$
H\psi(t)=i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}
$$
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian. Then the solution is given by 
$$
\psi(t)=\psi(0)e^{-iHt/\hbar}
$$
where much care needs to be taken in what $e^{-iHt/\hbar}$ means, but we take advantage of the analogy to regular ODE (and regular matrix exponentiation) in using the same notation. In this case, this is an unbounded operator (thanks to the momentum component), so care needs to be taken in defining what the exponential means.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the part “care needs to be taken in defining what the exponential means”?

Comment: it's a bit hard to do so in a stackexchange post and without assuming lots of previous knowledge (mostly of measure theory, up to say, the Riesz-Markov theorem). The idea is to define $f(A)$, where $f$ is any continuous (actually and eventually Borel) function via an integral of this function with respect to a suitable measure.

Comment: @Slayer147 In strongly attractive potentials a classical particle will spiral into the origin in a finite time. In QM the corresponding Hamiltonians may have more than one "self-adjoint"
 extension, each corresponding to a different unitary time evolution. See John Baez's [The Inverse Cube Force Law](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2015/08/30/the-inverse-cube-force-law/).

Answer (score 1):

Riesz Functional Calculus is applicable for any holomorphic function. Since, z -> exp(z) is an entire function so you can talk about exp(A) for any operator A on a Hilbert Space.

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (i.e. LaTeX commands) for mathematical notations.

Comment: I have a question,If $A$ is a poistibe operator,$U$ is an unitary operator,can we deduce that  $e^{UAU^*}=Ue^AU^*$?